# window.print not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, printing, internet-explorer-9

The JavaScript function `window.print` is working in IE7 and 8, but not in IE9. Can someone help to fix this?

Comment: Hey Suganya, and welcome to SO. Can you please be more descriptive? can you show a piece of code that doesn't work? Nobody here can help you unless you make them understand your problem and narrow it down.

Comment: So has anyone found a fix yet? I still have this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
onClick="javascript:window.print();
return false;
```

Comment: Why do you have a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) without a loop?

Comment: This answer probably is not helpful.  This means you would have to click on something, whereas Suganya does not necessarily need onClick behavior.  Additionally, mixing JavaScript and html is not recommended.  See http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#introduction for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick="window.print(delay*1000); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do few things.

1. Add a  in the
2. close the document properly: `mywindow.document.close();`
3. do focus on the documnet: `mywindow.focus();`
4. then write the print code: `mywindow.print();`

exp:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'My Print Data', 'width=850,scrollbars=yes');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Page</title><meta http-    equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE8"/>');
..........
.........
.........
...........
mywindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');
mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();
mywindow.print();
```

Comment: This answer is not very clear... Point 1) Add a in the,,, what?